# New Certificate - PKIX path building failed

Tags: ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate, cas

I have just bought a new wildcard ssl certificate for our domain as our old one is about to expire.
I have installed it on our cas server and our application server, however I am getting the following stacktrace on our app server:

```
Message: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
Cause: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Trace:
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(Saml11TicketValidator.java:231)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:207)
```

The certificate is identical on both servers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the GoDaddy certificate in the JVM had expired, was no longer trusted, or had a different path to the new one.

I therefore had to import the latest certificate bundle from GoDaddy into my JVM on my jetty server.

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias godaddy -file /tmp/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/oracle-jdk1.7/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```